# Pivot and order multiple columns in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I know how to pivot a query in oracle but i need to order the result by the columns

This is the table:

```
Customer_id   Month   Sales_amt   Bill_amt
1             1       10          10
2             1       20          20
3             1       30          30
1             2       20          20
2             2       20          0
3             2       30          30
```

If I do the pivot sentence

```
SELECT * 
  FROM t
 PIVOT (
        SUM(sales_amt) AS sales, SUM(bill_amt) AS bill FOR month IN (1,2)
       );
```

The result is:

```
Customer_id   1_sales 1_bill 2_sales 2_bill 
1             10      10     20      20
```

But I need to get first the sales columns and after the bill columns

```
Customer_id   1_sales 2_sales 1_bill 2_bill 
1             10      20      10      20
```

How can I get this order pls?

EDIT: I need to do this in a dynamic way because i'm going to use it for an authomatized report

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the current query to the one which contains conditional aggregation logic such as

```
SELECT customer_id, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN month = 1 THEN sales_amt END) AS "1_SALES",
       SUM(CASE WHEN month = 2 THEN sales_amt END) AS "2_SALES",
       SUM(CASE WHEN month = 1 THEN bill_amt END) AS "1_BILL",
       SUM(CASE WHEN month = 2 THEN bill_amt END) AS "2_BILL"
  FROM t
 GROUP BY customer_id
```

in order to make those columns ordered.

To make the query dynamic use the following code which creates a stored function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Get_Pivoted_Sales RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
  v_recordset SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_sql       VARCHAR2(32767);
  v_cols      VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
  SELECT LISTAGG('SUM(CASE WHEN month='||month||' THEN '||column_name||' END) AS "'||cn||'"',',') 
          WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY column_name DESC, month )        
    INTO v_cols
    FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT month,column_name,month||'_'||RTRIM(column_name,'_AMT') AS cn
             FROM t
            CROSS JOIN ( SELECT column_name
                           FROM user_tab_cols 
                          WHERE table_name = 'T' 
                            AND column_name NOT IN ('CUSTOMER_ID','MONTH') ) ); 

  v_sql :='SELECT customer_id,'|| v_cols ||'
             FROM t
            GROUP BY customer_id';

  OPEN v_recordset FOR v_sql;
  RETURN v_recordset;
END;
/
```

where the table is assumed to be created as

```
CREATE TABLE t
(
  customer_id INT,
  month       INT,
  sales_amt   NUMBER,
  bill_amt    NUMBER
)
```

and then call the function from *SQL Developer*'s console as

```
SQL> DECLARE
    res SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
   :res := Get_Pivoted_Sales;
END;
/

SQL> PRINT res;
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy - don't select `*`, select the explicit columns, in the order you need them.

Note that you will need to use double-quotes around the automatically-named columns if they begin with digits (and the rest of the column name will be in all-caps, not how you show them).

Something like this:

```
select customer_id, "1_SALES", "2_SALES", "1_BILL", "2_BILL" [ ... ]
from   ...
..........
```

While you are doing this, you may also give the columns more standard names (so they don't begin with digits, and therefore they don't need to be in double-quotes).

Comment: Is it a dynamic way to do this? I'm using the month as a date with a 'YYYYMM' format for data of 3 years ago. I don't want to make this manually each year.